# React cannot find entry file in any of the roots update

Tags: react-native

I have the following warning when running `react-native run-ios`:
[image]

I know that the question was asked before, but the solutions doesn't seem to work for me... I restarted my OS and it's still not working...

Any ideas?

Comment: I noticed this problem started with the latest version (0.45.0). A lot of people are having problems, you can check this (https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/14376#issuecomment-306922288) github thread for possible workarounds.

Comment: I created project with the same name and pasted everything in it, it takes 30 seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue now is with the current version of react-native: `0.45.0`.

I downgraded to the `0.44.0` version with [`react-native-git-upgrade 0.44.0`](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/tree/master/react-native-git-upgrade) and it works fine now!

Comment: If you want to use 0.45.0 though, you can try the workaround I listed in my answer.  LIke you, I am sticking with 0.44 for now though :).

Answer (score 2):

As I noted in the comments, you can check this [github link](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/14376#issuecomment-306922288)

The workaround from that thread that seems to work consistently (at least in my case) is to do these steps:

1. In the current terminal: `react-native start`
2. In another terminal: `react-native run-android`